# Как изолировать события псевдоклассов в CSS?

Tags: css, style

```
<li onClick={() => route.post('/user1')}>
  User1 <button onClick={handleDeleteUser}>Удалить</button>
</li>
```

CSS

```
li {
  background-color: white,

  &:active {
    background-color: gray,
  }
}

button {
  background-color: red,

  &:active {
    background-color: dark-red,
  }
}
```

В данном примере при клике на button срабатывает active для li.
Как изолировать клик по кнопке, что бы для родительского элемента не срабатывало событие клика?

Comment: лучше всего не вкладывать один активный элемент внутрь другого

Answer (score 0):

> Как изолировать клик по кнопке, что бы для родительского элемента не срабатывало событие клика?

Остановить всплытие события...

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  // остановка всплытия события
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log('button')
})
```

```html
<li onclick='console.log("li")'>
  User1 <button>Удалить</button>
</li>
```

Более подробно в учебнике https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling